# How to make a call to outside function from the controllers/models in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to C# MVC. I am trying to create a class where can I can put all the reusable functions and I want to have the ability to call those functions from my controllers and models. Is it possible to do so?

Here is my project folder structure:

[image]

So I have created a Helpers folder and inside it I have a commonFunctions class. 
For now I have one function inside it.

```
namespace myProject.Helpers
{
    public class CommonFunctions
    {
        public static string GenerateSHA(string sString)
        {
            string result = "";
            SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] password = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sString));
            result = Encoding.Default.GetString(password);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call that function from my model. How can I do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the BuildAction of the CommonFunctions file set to 'Compile'?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily call that function like this:

```
var sha = Helpers.CommonFunctions.GenerateSHA("Your String");
```

Or you can add `using` statement and call the function without namespace specification every time:

```
using myProject.Helpers;

// And somewhere in your classes
var sha = CommonFunctions.GenerateSHA("Your String");
```

Comment: it doesnot work. I get error: The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'myProject' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: You provided a screenshot of your project's structure and it seems like it contains models and helpers. If your models are in different project then you need to add reference to this assembly. Also it seems that "myProject" is just a name you use not to disclose your real project's name. Please make that you change it back when copy-paste some code form here

Answer (score 1):

It is a direct call like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace myProject.Models
{
    public class YourViewModel
    {
        public YourViewModel()
        {

             //This is the constructor of the class
            //Call the function you need
           var tVar = Helpers.CommonFunctions.GenerateSHA("String to process");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does it display?!

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'myProject' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: (YourViewModel) should be added in the (Models) folder in (myProject)